Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpl in java.library.path:
I got this error when I try to connect prolog to my java project,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpl in java.library.path:
/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib    at
java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2458)    at
java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:916)    at
java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:2063)  at
org.jpl7.JPL.loadNativeLibrary(JPL.java:112)  at
org.jpl7.fli.Prolog.(Prolog.java:70)  at
org.jpl7.Query.open(Query.java:300)   at
org.jpl7.Util.textToTerm(Util.java:127)   at
org.jpl7.Query.(Query.java:185)     at
org.mtm.Main.main(Main.java:8)

And this is my java code;

import org.jpl7.Query;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Query q = new Query("consult('kb.pl')");
} }


In windows I connect prolog with java by adding these variables to the environment;

SWI_HOME_DIR C:\Program Files\swipl
%SWI_HOME_DIR%\bin %SWI_HOME_DIR%\lib\jpl.jar

but in linux(Ubuntu 22.04) I don't know how to do that. If anyone can help me to solve this.

I download the jpl library and add it to the .bashrc but the
issue is same.
Also I created the java project in maven and add jpl
dependency to pom.xml but issue is same.


I download the jpl library and add it to the .bashrc but the issue is same. That unfortunately doesn't show/tell us what you did. Probably (not mentioned in the exception) /usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/x86_64-linux should be in java.library.path

@g00se oh sorry for that, I download the library and then I add it location to the .bashrc like this,export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/Java_Libraries/jar_files/jpl-7.4.0.jar '

Yes, that would be why it doesn't work. If the shared library is in that jar, then java will not know about it. It's not PATH that's used for that. It's java.library.path and that should work per my previous comment. The shared library needs to be extracted from any archive
